# Python slice notation

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I am attempting to understand some of the example code from machinelearningmastery.com but the slice notation is throwing me off... For starters with my code I am attempting to make a simple regression type ML algorithm with some data from a CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd

McheLrn = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/data.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)


McheLrn['month'] = McheLrn.index.month
McheLrn['date'] = McheLrn.index.strftime('%d')
McheLrn['hour'] = McheLrn.index.strftime('%H')
McheLrn['Day_of_week'] = McheLrn.index.dayofweek

McheLrn.head()
```

This will output:

```
    OSAT    kWh month   date    hour    Day_of_week
Date                        
2013-01-01 06:00:00 10.4    16.55   1   01  06  1
2013-01-01 06:15:00 10.4    16.55   1   01  06  1
2013-01-01 06:30:00 10.4    16.05   1   01  06  1
2013-01-01 06:35:00 10.4    16.05   1   01  06  1
2013-01-01 06:45:00 10.4    17.20   1   01  06  1
```

Not sure if I am using the correct terminology, but the dependent variable is `kWh` (Y variable) and all other are independent variables for my X variables...

With the code below what is throwing me off is the slice notation `X = array[:,0:2] Y = array[:,2]` And I am not sure if I have my X & Y variables correctly selected.

```
# Decision Tree Regression
import pandas
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor


dataframe = McheLrn
array = dataframe.values

X = array[:,0:2]
Y = array[:,2]

seed = 7
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=90, random_state=seed)
model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error'
results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)

print(results.mean())
```

Comment: `array[None:None, 0:2]` is the same as all lines, columns 0 and 1, `array[None:None, 2] is all lines, column 2.

Comment: in the `McheLrn.head()` how do I specify to use 'kWh' variable for Y and everything else for X variables...?

Comment: The code works but I am not sure if I have the slice notation correct

Comment: I don't think there is an error, I just don't think he understands the slice notation. `X = array[:,0:2]` means use all rows denoted by the first `:` before the comma, then `0:2` after the comma means use columns 0 up until 2 (not including 2) so you could also do `[:,:2]` and reproduce the same output.

Comment: So according to sliced columns 2 columns are in X and one last column in Y. If that is the case then your slicing is okay

Comment: The second column `kWh` is what I want to use for my Y variable and all else use for X variables... What should the dot notation look like for that?

Comment: `array[:, [col for col in range(array.shape[1]) if col != 2]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to illustrate further. If you know the target column(name) then preferred method would be to select everything other than target column like this

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[2,3],'c':[1,9]})
target_col=['c'] # column 'c' is the target column here
X=df[list(set(df.columns).difference(target_col))].values # X-> features
Y=df[target_col].values # Y -> target
```

If using the column numbers. Assuming last column is target column

```
data=df.values
X=data[:,:2] # from column 1 upto second last column including all the rows
Y=data[:,2] # only last column(target) including all the rows
```